# How to use std::sample together with QSet?

Tags: c++, qt, c++17

I have a `QSet` and want to use a random unique subset of it. Is it anyhow (without much code) possible to use `std::sample` for it?

Following code failes, because `std::back_inserter` is looking for `QSet::push_back`, which doesn't exists.

```
std::mt19937 gen((std::random_device()()));
QSet<MyType> allOfMyTypes = {...};
QSet<MyType> selectedMyTypes;
std::sample(allOfMyTypes.begin(), allOfMyTypes.end(), std::back_inserter(selectedMyTypes), 4, gen);
```

Comment: @rafix That doesn't work because `QSet::insert` only accepts the value as a single argument. `std::inserter` requires an `insert` member function that also gets an iterator as the first argument.

Comment: @lubgr Damn, you are right, I should not answer on Friday after drinking beer :) thanks for it.